# Sieve of Eratosthenes algorithm - works fine but crashes after

Tags: c, primes, sieve-of-eratosthenes

newbie here:

the following program to generate all prime numbers under 100 using the "Sieve of Eratosthenes algorithm" works fine, but crashes after displaying the **CORRECT** output!

**the error in windows**: primenumber.exe has stopped working!

```
#include<stdio.h>
int main()
{
  int P[100] = {0}, i, j;

  for(i = 2; i < 100; ++i)
  {
    if(P[i] == 0)
      printf("%d\n", i);

    for(j = 1; i * j <= 100; ++j)
      P[i * j] = 1;
  }

  return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`i*j<=100` array index out of bound -- UB...([Undefined Behavior](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Undefined_behavior))

It should be `i*j<100`.

Answer (score 2):

there is an array overflow occurring here

```
 i*j<=100 should be i*j<100
```

because range of your array is 0-99